# Is there a moment about a frictionless pin

Tags: equilibrium, statics

In a structure that looks like this:[image]

We have two unknown forces at point A in the x and y directions respectively due to the frictionless pin support, and one unknown force in the y direction at B due to the roller. We also have a force in the negative y direction due to the weight of the truss, and known applied forces F1, F2, F3 with components in the -x and -y directions. We can use 3 equilibrium equations to solve for the 3 unknown forces:
$\sum_{} Fx = 0$ to find Ax
$\sum_{} Fy = 0$ to find Ay
$\sum_{} Ma = 0$ to find By

It seems that the moment about A is calculated using the vertical components of the forces at F2, F3, and the weight as well as the upward force at B.

My question is - what about the moment about A due to the horizontal forces at F2 and F3? They are a perpendicular distance from A, and the frictionless pin does not prevent rotation, only translation. How is the truss in equilibrium?

Comment: It seems you are correct. The horizontal components of F1, F2, F3 contribute to torque about **A** with a moment arm the height of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to take the balance of torques **about any point**.

That's because we assume the whole structure to be motionless, so it doesn't translate but also doesn't rotate about any chosen axis (which would run through that point, like $A$ or $B$ or whatever your choice may be) Make a choice that is mathematically the most convenient.

---

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the angles with the horizontal of $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$ respectively.

The vertical balance of forces is:

$$F_1\sin\alpha+F_2\sin\beta+F_3\sin\gamma+W=F_{A,y}+F_{B,y}$$

The horizontal balance of forces is:

$$F_1\cos\alpha+F_2\cos\beta+F_3\cos\gamma=F_{A,x}$$

Let $L$ be the distance between $A$ and $B$, then the balance of torques about $A$ is:

$$F_2\sin\beta \frac{L}{2}-F_2\cos\beta \frac{L}{2}+F_3\sin\gamma L-F_3\cos\gamma L+W\frac{L}{2}=F_{B,y}L$$

From these three simultaneous equations $F_{A,x}$, $F_{A,y}$ and $F_{B,y}$ can be calculated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119984/discussion-on-answer-by-gert-is-there-a-moment-about-a-frictionless-pin).

Comment: Y'all. Chat. It's over there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a moment about a frictionless pin

As regards to the title of your post, there is no moment *reaction* at a frictionless pin. For equilibrium the sum of the moments about A has to equal zero without including any moment reaction at A.

> My question is - what about the moment about A due to the horizontal
> forces at F2 and F3? They are a perpendicular distance from A, and the
> frictionless pin does not prevent rotation, only translation. How is
> the truss in equilibrium?

The sum of the moments about A should include contributions from all forces and reactions, including the applicable horizontal components of the three applied forces. In order for the truss to be in static equilibrium the sum of the moments about any  point on the truss have to be zero, including the sum of the moments about A. While it has already been pointed out that any point can be chosen, one should pick a point that eliminates as many variables as possible. For the sole purpose of determining the reaction at B, the sum of the moments about A is the logical choice.

For simplicity, assume the magnitudes of all three applied forces are equal to $F$ and that the angle with the horizontal of all three forces is $\theta$. Further assume the length of each horizontal and vertical member of the truss is $L$. Then if you take the sum of the moments about A you should obtain (I leave it to you to verify):

$$B_{y}=\frac{W+3F(\sin\theta - \cos\theta)}{2}$$

Since the reaction of the roller support at B can only be upward, we have the additional constraint for equilibrium that $B_{y}\ge0$. Otherwise the truss will rotate counter clockwise. Therefore, for equilibrium

$$\frac{W+3F(\sin\theta - \cos\theta)}{2}\ge0$$

Note that if $\theta =0$ (the forces are purely horizontal),

$$B_{y}=\frac{W-3F}{2}$$

Then, given the minimum requirement for equilibrium of $B_{y}= 0$ then $W=3F$. This is evident from the diagram because if all three forces are purely horizontal and if there is no downward reaction at B, then only the weight $W$ would be preventing counter clockwise rotation about A.

Finally, we see that in this example, in order for the structure to be in equilibrium it is necessary that $\theta \ge 45^0$. Anything less would require a downward reaction of the roller, which can not occur.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it's interesting but your simplification really... *simplifies* it enormously.

Comment: @Gert See my additional last sentence. The point of the simplification is not to solve a particular problem, but to demonstrate that one must include the horizontal components of the the three forces to determine equilibrium and to determine $B_y$. That was the OP's doubt. Those torques from the horizontal components reduces the upward reaction at $B$.

Comment: It would be easy to engineer a roller that can provide a downward force but I take your point, which I had noticed myself. It wasn't clear to me that that was the OP's doubt though...

Comment: @Gert Perhaps, but in statics the standard for roller supports is for upward reactions only. But whether there is or is not an downward reaction, the horizontal components of the forces need to be taken into account to determine the reaction at B. Those components reduce the upward reaction, all else being equal.

Comment: I don't know about 'standard'. Think of a tall and narrow shelving system. One way of preventing it toppling over (rotating) is to tether it to the floor. The tether then provides a downward force when needed.